# How to SELECT if user is the owner of the notes? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have 2 tables: 'users' and 'notes'.

My 'users' MYSQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And my 'notes' MYSQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE `notes` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How do I make e.g. "Bob"(id of 2 in 'users') a owner of note "Math"(id of 1 in 'notes')?

Here is my SELECT for only 'notes':

```
SELECT title, content FROM notes WHERE id = :id
```

My intentions are; I want users have their own notes for themselves and not others.

Comment: you need a relation between  the two table  .. you need  a column in notes table for refer the user id  in user table

Comment: so I create a new column in notes table, e.g.>> `usersid` int NOT NULL, <<?

Comment: @scaisEdge: while this could be done, a junction table is more general and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table called `Note_Owner` or something like that, with the following fields:

```
users_id - the id of a user in the users table
notes_id - the id of a note in the notes table
```

Make the combination of users_id and notes_id the primary key. Also, make the `notes_id` column unique, so that a given note can't appear more than once.

This is known as a "junction table".

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column user_id in yoru notes table

```
CREATE TABLE `notes` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int 
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and you can join user and notes eg:

```
 SELECT a.username, b.title, b.content
  FROM user a 
  INNER JOIN notes a.id = b.user_id
  WHERE a.id = :id
```

NB assumin that the id for Bob is 3 then in the notes  related  to bob you must inseer  user_id = 3

Comment: It did not work, stayed as the same, but it inserted a "0" inside users_id and I can still see Bob's note as e.g. James.

Comment: you must insert in all the rows of notes related to  Bob the same value of Bob id ...(not 0)   .. asnwer updated  with a brief suggestion hope is clear .

Comment: So: $user_id=a.id(id of Bob) then `INSERT INTO notes (title, user_id, content, created) VALUES (:title, :user_id, :content, null)` And :user_id = $user_id?

Comment: Ok, I understand now but how do I actually do that - assign user_id to Bob? Do I need PHP to do that?

Comment: when you insert bob  the db assign (an autoincrement) a value to  the user id  .. so the question is not how you  can assigne the user_id to bob but how you can assign the value to the user_id in notes  . .... you can manage both the insert (or the query you need) with a server side language eg: php  ..